# How do I access Wordpress core files like wp-content on google cloud after doing one click install?

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, filezilla, gcloud

I have experience installing wordpress websites on hosting where we have a cpanel to access the core files. What is the equivalent on Google Cloud?

I have tried to find a solution to this and I have installed gcloud and Filezilla. With gcloud, I was able to get public and private keys. However, when I added the private key to Filezilla, I have not been able to connect to the Wordpress host IP address. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/wordpress/) click-to deploy and you want use a different tool instead of gcloud read [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#standardssh).

After you connect to the VM, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/wordpress/deployment-details), you find WP files in

```
4. Creates a data disk and mounts it in the /wordpress directory (A symlink points from /var/www to this directory)
```